# How to get custom rows in Pentaho?

Tags: mysql, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have one table with some information.

```
        Name  Age  Address
        Tejas  20   xyz
        Jeffie 21   por
        jason  19   brazil
```

This table i get from query.I want to show row which has age less than 20 with green and greater than 20 is red.(Note:Whole row should get the color).Is there Addins for tables for such scenario? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you talking about Pentaho report designer (PRD) ?

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon Pentaho CDE for designing dashboards